# How to convert column to list in expressions in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I was earlier able to convert column to `list` but  it is not working now after the `latest version update`.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1,4,4,7,7,10,10,13,16],
        "B": [2,5,5,8,18,11,11,14,17],
        "C": [3,6,6,9,9,12,12,15,18]        
    }
)
```

I have also referred to [polars_list_link](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/lists/#creating-a-list-column) but below code is not working

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('B').sum().over('A').alias("sum[B]/A_groups"),
    pl.col("A").list.head(2).alias("list_A"),
    pl.col("A").list.lengths().alias("length"),
)
```

**Error**
SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected `List`, got `i64`

**Update**
Expected Results

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ sum[B]/A_groups │list_A length
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64             │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 2               │[1,4]   9
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 10              │[1,4]   9
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 10              │[1,4]   9
│ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ 26              │[1,4]   9
│ 7   ┆ 18  ┆ 9   ┆ 26              │[1,4]   9
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ 22              │[1,4]   9
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ 22              │[1,4]   9
│ 13  ┆ 14  ┆ 15  ┆ 14              │[1,4]   9
│ 16  ┆ 17  ┆ 18  ┆ 17              │[1,4]   9
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────────────┘
```

Later I will use this with window partitioning for these to make more sense.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have updated the post with expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the data from the `Expr` directly using the `Expr` functions `head` and `len`. Because the `head` returns multiple values, you can `implode` to convert the results to a list.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1,4,4,7,7,10,10,13,16],
        "B": [2,5,5,8,18,11,11,14,17],
        "C": [3,6,6,9,9,12,12,15,18]        
    }
)

print(df.with_columns(
    pl.col('B').sum().over('A').alias("sum[B]/A_groups"),
    pl.col("A").head(2).implode().alias("list_A"),
    pl.col("A").len().alias("length"),
))
```

Results:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────────────┬───────────┬────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ sum[B]/A_groups ┆ list_A    ┆ length │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---             ┆ ---       ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64             ┆ list[i64] ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 2               ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 10              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 10              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ 26              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 7   ┆ 18  ┆ 9   ┆ 26              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ 22              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ 22              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 13  ┆ 14  ┆ 15  ┆ 14              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
│ 16  ┆ 17  ┆ 18  ┆ 17              ┆ [1, 4]    ┆ 9      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────────────┴───────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: I tried creating a `list` by `window partition` using `implode` but that doesn't work. `pl.col('B').implode().over('A').alias("group_list")`, Any idea how that could be done ?

Comment: @ViSa - I'll see if I can answer in your new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77018917/how-to-convert-column-to-list-over-groups-in-expressions-in-polars).