# How to convert column to list over groups in expressions in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I am not able to create a `list` of values for each group from another column.

**Data**

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1,4,4,7,7,10,10,13,16],
        "B": [2,5,5,8,18,11,11,14,17],
        "C": [3,6,6,9,9,12,12,15,18]        
    }
)
```

**Tried**

```
df.with_columns(pl.col('B').implode().over('A').alias("group_list"))
```

**Error**

**Update**
Expected output:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │group_list
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │[2]
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │[5,5]
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │[5,5]
│ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   │[8,18]
│ 7   ┆ 18  ┆ 9   │[8,18]
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  │[11,11]
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  │[11,11]
│ 13  ┆ 14  ┆ 15  │[14]
│ 16  ┆ 17  ┆ 18  │[17]
```

Comment: Can you include expected output?

Comment: @keraion I have added the `Expected output` in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `mapping_strategy` of `over` to `join` to get the `list` creation behavior.

I would also note the warning: `join: Join the groups as 'List<group_dtype>' to the row positions. warning: this can be memory intensive.`

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1,4,4,7,7,10,10,13,16],
        "B": [2,5,5,8,18,11,11,14,17],
        "C": [3,6,6,9,9,12,12,15,18]        
    }
)

print(df.with_columns(
    pl.col("B").over("A", mapping_strategy="join").alias("group_list"),
))
```

Results:

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ group_list │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64]  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ [2]        │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ [5, 5]     │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ [5, 5]     │
│ 7   ┆ 8   ┆ 9   ┆ [8, 18]    │
│ 7   ┆ 18  ┆ 9   ┆ [8, 18]    │
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ [11, 11]   │
│ 10  ┆ 11  ┆ 12  ┆ [11, 11]   │
│ 13  ┆ 14  ┆ 15  ┆ [14]       │
│ 16  ┆ 17  ┆ 18  ┆ [17]       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────────┘
```